# A company with n women and m men as employees is deciding which employees to promote.

Tags: probability

A company with n women and m men as employees is deciding which employees to promote.

a) Suppose for this part that the company decides to promote t employees, where $1 ≤ t ≤ n + m$, by choosing t random employees (with equal probabilities for each set of t employees). What is the distribution of the number of women who get promoted?

b) Now suppose that instead of having a predetermined number of promotions to give, the company decides independently for each employee, promoting the employee with probability p. Find the distribution of the number of women who are promoted and the number of employees who are promoted.

Hint: HGeom for a) and Bin for b).

- I figured out part A and got the answer to be $P(W=k)$=$\binom{n}{k}$$\binom{m}{t-k}$/$\binom{n+m}{t}$ where k = women who get promoted, t-k = men who get promoted, and w = # of women that are promoted. W~HGeom(n,m,t) with PMF.
- For part B I got the distribution of the number of women who are promoted to be W~B(n,p) with W = # of women that are promoted and the distribution of the number of people promoted to be x~B(n+m,p) with x = # of people that are promoted. However, I feel like my answer is missing something or it is incorrect. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Your answer looks good

Comment: Maybe you should say that $p=\frac{n}{n+m}$.